# function imagettftext undefined on php 7.4

Tags: php, imagettftext

how i can use imagettftext  on php 7.4
I already build with configure
./configure   --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs   --with-pgsql=/usr/local/psqllib   --enable-soap   --with-bz2   --with-curl   --with-gettext   --with-zlib   --enable-ftp   --enable-sockets   --enable-cli   --enable-opcache   --with-mysqli   --with-openssl   --with-ldap   --with-libdir=/lib64   --with-iconv   --enable-mbstring   --disable-mbregex   --enable-gd   --with-zip --with-freetype

Comment: You tagged this as "php". The subject reads as "function... undefined"; how exactly and what is the full error and code? That function has no special notes about 7.4 https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php

Comment: i know that function not support with 7.4 but i need to use relate version of php with my project so i build with 7.4.2 and can fix this problem thanks