# Writing text on image using GD is not working

Tags: php, gd

I'm using `PHP 7.4` and when i try to write text on image using `imagettftext()` function nothing happen only blank image! when i roll back to `PHP 5.6` it works perfect.

I've confirmed that GD is enabled and i'm under windows OS

Here is my code (i have copied it from [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php)):

```
// Set the content-type
header('Content-Type: image/png');

// Create the image
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 30);

// Create some colors
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $white);

// The text to draw
$text = 'Testing...';
// Replace path by your own font path
$font = 'arial.ttf';

// Add some shadow to the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 11, 21, $grey, $font, $text);

// Add the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $text);

// Using imagepng() results in clearer text compared with imagejpeg()
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Is it true that “[function imagettftext undefined on php 7.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59889765/function-imagettftext-undefined-on-php-7-4)”?

Comment: Did you read the documentation? “ Note: This function is only available if PHP is compiled with freetype support”.

Comment: The code works for me under w10 with php 7.4.2 and $font = "C:\\ Windows\\ Fonts\\arial.ttf";

Comment: The code above works fine for me also with the correct path chosen

Comment: @emix yes i've read that note but i'm using shared hosting and i do not have an access to install freetype.

Comment: @jspit i'm using Windows 10 as OS and PHP version 7.4.11

Comment: Your code does not have the correct path for the font! Comment out the line with the header so that you can see the error messages.

Comment: @jspit that was correct, i should have to include the real path of the used font .. it works only in this case ~ thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the font should be the Problem here.
You should include it with a path. Read the documentation at [php:imagettftext](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php)

> Depending on which version of the GD library PHP is using, when fontfile does not begin with a leading / then .ttf will be appended to the filename and the library will attempt to search for that filename along a library-defined font path.

> When using versions of the GD library lower than 2.0.18, a space character, rather than a semicolon, was used as the 'path separator' for different font files. Unintentional use of this feature will result in the warning message: Warning: Could not find/open font. For these affected versions, the only solution is moving the font to a path which does not contain spaces.

So you should make sure where the font is. Or try different combinations with leading "/" or without the file extension

Comment: Well! when i try to include the real path of the used font ... it works :) thanks a lot @Alexander Klement